# (Qt) Rendering scene, different items in the same relative positions

Tags: qt, view, printing, render, scene

I have a QSqlTableModel model that contains my data. 
I have made a QGraphicsScene scene  and a QGraphicsView view so the user can move around same myQGraphicsTextItem text items until the desired position.

Something like this:

```
myQWidget::myQWidget()
{
    //these are member of my class
    chequeScene = new QGraphicsScene();
    chequeView = new QGraphicsView();
    model = new QSQLTableModel();

    //populate model, inialize things here...

    //add predefined items to the scene
    setScene();
}
```

there's a button to show the view and move the textitems of scene. It works well.

there's a button that calls the slot print that belongs to the class. It configures a QPrinter and then calls the following paint method myQWidget::paint(), after that scene->render() is called.

The porpoise of the method below is to print data on a paper that is configured to have the same size than the scene while printing the data in the same relative position the textItem had on the scene. Can't do it with QList it doesn't order the items in the same way I added them to the scene.
Here is my code below, it prints with overlapping of some fields doe to QList order items as they appear on the scene.

```
void myQWidget::paint()
{
    qreal dx = 0;
    qreal dy = 0;
    QList<QGraphicsItem*> L = chequeScene->items();

    for (int j=0; j<model->columnCount(); j++) {


        if(!L.isEmpty())
        {
            //Saves the position on dx, dy
           dx = L.first()->scenePos().x();
           dy = L.first()->scenePos().y();
           chequeScene->removeItem( L.first() );
           delete L.first();
           L.removeFirst();
        }



        QString txt("");

        //selecting printing formar for each column
        switch(j)
        {
           case COLUMNADEFECHA:
              txt = QDate::fromString(model->data(model->index(chequenum,j)).toString(), "yyyy/MM/dd").toString("dd/MM/yyyy");
              break;
           case COLUMNADECHEQUES:
              break;
           default:
               txt = model->data(model->index(chequenum,j)).toString();
               break;


        }

        //filtering not important columns
        if(j!=COLUMNADECHEQUES)
        {
           //Supposubly item with the desired information is added to the scene
           //on the same position it had before. Not working.
           GraphicsTextItem *item=new GraphicsTextItem();
           item->setPlainText(txt);
           item->setPos(dx,dy);
           chequeScene->addItem(item);
        }

    }
}
```

Any idea on how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I think as you are getting the scenePos in dx and dy but are setting it using `setPos` function.
Also as you are using your GraphicsTextItem and not QGraphicsTextItem maybe a look at your paint method will help in understanding the problem.

Try using `item->mapFromScene(dx, dy)` and then use those coordinates to set the item position by `item->setPos(..)`.

Hope This Helps..